# How can I prevent this $.getJSON from multiplying every time I click on a button?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm learning more about jQuery's `$.getJSON` on w3schools.com. So how can I make this code generate a JSON object just one time?

Regardless how many times the button is pressed. Here's the code that I'm talking about which is attach to a code editor. Here's the [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_getjson) and the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.getJSON("demo_ajax_json.js", function(result){
            $.each(result, function(i, field){
                $("div").append(field + " ");
            });
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Get JSON data</button>

<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean "generate a JSON object just one time"?

Comment: `I'm learning more about jQuery's $.getJSON on w3schools.com` Please don't. W3Schools are often outdated in their guidance, and sometimes even just plain wrong. There's no better guide for jQuery than the official documentation: http://api.jquery.com & http://learn.jquery.com. I'd strongly suggest you use those instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `click` you can bind with `one`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").one("click", function(){
        $.getJSON("demo_ajax_json.js", function(result){
            $.each(result, function(i, field){
                $("div").append(field + " ");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

> The .one() method is identical to .on(), except that the handler for a given element and event type is unbound after its first invocation

You can find more info about the `one` method [here](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

Comment: Than you so much eltonkamami the others method were good as well but your method is closer to the original structure so it works perfectly thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with one more solution using a variable

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var clickedOnce = false;
  $("button").click(function(){
    if(!clickedOnce){
      clickedOnce = true;
      $.getJSON("demo_ajax_json.js", function(result){
          $.each(result, function(i, field){
              $("div").append(field + " ");
          });
      });
    }  
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Get JSON data</button>

<div></div>
```

One more solution using `CSS` property `pointer-events:none;`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.getJSON("demo_ajax_json.js", function(result){
      $.each(result, function(i, field){
        $("div").append(field + " ");
      });
    }); 
    $(this).css({
      'pointer-events': 'none'
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Get JSON data</button>

<div></div>
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script 
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            $.getJSON("demo_ajax_json.js", function(result){
                $.each(result, function(i, field){
                    $("div").append(field + " ");
                };
                return false;
            );
      });
   });
});
</script>
```

On success return false, this script will work once. Or you may hide or disable this button.